# iPhone iOS7 apps stay open in App Store after install

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore, ios

How does one remove a downloaded and installed app from the App Store Purchases page?

Deleting and re-installing does not seem to work. There is a very long discussion stream on the Apple forums about this particularly minor seeming but very annoying phenomena. Moreover, there doesn't seem to be any applicable, actionable solutions except to wait several days for the apps to go away. The "OPEN" just sits there.

Comment: Did you try logging out of your Apple Account and back in?

Answer (score 1):

To remove from my updates page I merely went to Settings, under **Date and Time** and toggled off **Set automatically** and changed the date and time a few weeks ahead. You can change the settings back after checking your app page to see that they're gone. It works!

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Of course, I don't understand why. Only certain apps exhibit this behavior of getting stuck. (wTw)

Comment: I have to say that there is a problem with the solution: like Sisyphus, you have to keep pushing this rock up the hill. There is always another app that will get stuck OPEN in the App Store even after the install is done. So, what's a permanent solution?